# Align View to plane of selection

Tags: modeling

[image: Step 1. Create Bezier Curve and apply extrude and offset.]

Hi, 
I am trying to create a mesh out of bezier curve extrude section...
[image: Step 2. Convert curve to mesh]
Then going into edit mode and selecting 2 vertices as shown and cursor to selected.
[image: Step 3. Cursor to selected]

In this view if I try to rotate then the rotation is about the view axis and is wrong.
[image: Rotate without aligning on axis...]

If instead I first align the view manually to the plane of vertices
[image: Align about the axis of plane of vertices]
and then rotate the vertices by 90 deg then it is done correctly.
[image: Now rotation by 90 deg is aligned]

How can I make blender align the view to the plane of rotation?

Ctrl + Shift + NUMPAD 3 doesn't always align the view to the front view of the plane of selection.

I am ok to code this in python if anyone can throw me some pointers...

Many thanks,
Cody

Comment: Are you trying to position the camera solely for rotating the edges, or do you need that for other purposes as well?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting your face and using Shift+(NUMPAD 1,3, or 7) should allow you to get all the angles you want. Also hitting Numpad 9 will flip you 180 to the other side of the face.